# Write a derivative operator without denominator using diffcoef

Tags: xtemplate, diffcoeff

I recently discovered the [`diffcoef` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/diffcoeff) and the power of [`xtemplate`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xtemplate). The first one encompasses almost everything I was doing with personal macros for derivative operators.

However, I was wondering if it is possible to simply tune the command `\diffp` to obtain a compact version of the derivative operator, where the denominator is subscripted instead.

Here is a MWE, where the right hand side of the equation should look like the left hand side:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{diffcoeff}

\begin{document}

    \diffdef{p}{ % Something that should remove the fraction style
        op-symbol = \partial,
        op-symbol-alt = none
        }
    \begin{equation}
        \partial_x f= \diffp*{f}{x} % now the LHS and RHS are different...
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Of course the purpose is not to do something like `\newcommand{\diff2}[2]{\dlp_{#1}#2}` because I would like to retain the flexibility of the `diffcoef` package. For example, I also wish to be able to write with the same command:

```
\partial_{\frac{1}{b}}^{z}\partial_{xy}^{z-1}a=\diffp[z,z-1]{a}{\frac{1}{b},xy}
```

So is it possible to remove the fraction style of the `\diffp` command with [`diffcoef`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/diffcoeff)? If not, is it possible to implement a new command, which maintains the syntax and flexibility of `\diffp` (perhaps via [`xtemplate`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xtemplate))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `derivative` might have the functionality you seek with it's `\pdif` command. The package uses a key-value interface for setting options. This can be done on a individual basis that only apply to a single differential/derivative e.g. `\pdif[key-value]{x,y,z}`. One can also set the options for all differentials /derivatives with `\derivset{\MacroName}[key-value]`, with `\MacroName` being `\pdif`, `\pdv` or other derivatives/differentials defined by the packages or you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{derivative}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        \pdif[order={z,z-1}]{\frac{1}{b},xy}  a \\
        \pdif*[order={z,z-1}]{\frac{1}{b},xy} a \\
        \pdif[style-notation=single, order={z,z-1}]{\frac{1}{b},xy} a \\
        \pdif[style-notation=multiple, order={z,z-1}]{\frac{1}{b},xy} a \\
        \pdif[style-notation=mixed, order={z,z-1}]{\frac{1}{b},xy} a \\
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, if one wants other macros names for them, I suggest defining new ones with the commands in section 5 of the documentation.

[image]

Comment: As I understand, the variable a in you answer is not really catch by the command, because it is not suppose to receive quantity to derive. As example, you can not give the option `fun` to the command `\pdif` because it does not expect a second mandatory argument. This is why I think it should more be a `\pdv` option: something like `\pdv[style=compact]{a}{b}`. Are you `derivative` author ? If yes, I can give more details on github and maybe help the implementation, if you want.

Comment: @R.N Yes, I'm the author of the package and you are welcome to contact me on github or by email. I implemented the `single` and `mixed` options specifically for this purpose you want. I didn't consider it crucial to grab the function, and I don't think an implementation through `\pdv` and friends would be good. Lets take the discussion of implementation on github/email.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the package defines `\dl.p.` and `\dlp` to write partial differential. From what I understand from the documentation, when you use `\diffdef{variant}{key-value}` you define both `\diff.variant.` and `\dl.variant.`. Then it is just a matter of defining `\NewDocumentCommand\SomeOtherName{}{ \diff.variant. }` if you don't want to use dots.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{diffcoeff}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        \dl.p.{x} \dlp{x} \\
        \dl.p._{x} \dlp_{x}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, there are other packages with these features as well.

Comment: @R.N I don't think `diffcoeff` support that functionality you seek, I'm afraid. You may want to take a look at the `derivative` package, which have this functionality, but implemented slightly different. It is a flexible package with similar features.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion about `derivative` package, I did not know it. Indeed, `diffcoeff` and `derivative` seems to have very similar features. However, from what I understood from the doc, the same distinction between `\diffp` and `\dlp` (diffcoeff) remains true between `\pdv` and  `\pdif` (derivative). Therefore, if you can propose a solution using `derivative` package with `\pdv` command,  I would accept it.